# How to subtract known substring from larger string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have been trying to deconstruct a string in the following way:

**Full String**

```
str = 'Hello world I am Bob'
```

**Substring 1**

```
sub_str1 = 'Hello world'
```

**Substring 2**

```
sub_str2 = 'world I'
```

**Desired Outcome:**

1. Using substring 1:

   Apply some regular expression to get:

   ```
   answer = ' I am Bob'
   ```
2. Using substring 2:

   ```
   answer = 'Hello  I am Bob'
   ```

I have tried a number of different approaches with regular expression, but I have just started using them and am not at all proficient.

Comment: [Regexr.com](http://regexr.com) is great for sorting this out

Comment: @VinnieJames Thanks for that website! Between it and [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), which I found when searching for the website you gave me, I think I can make a bit more sense of regular expression now.

Comment: Awesome! Checkout the sidebar on the site, it explains everything very clearly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can `replace` parts of a string with some other string.

*"Substracting"* would be replacing a substring with an empty string:

```
>>> 'Hello world I am Bob'.replace('Hello world', '')
' I am Bob'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just curious to know if you think this is faster than a regex?  I'd use timeit to test, but I can't figure out a regular expression that will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: `s/Hello world//` is the replacement regex

Comment: @aacealo Regex to find "Hello world" is "Hello world". This sam thing with regex would be `re.sub('Hello world', '', 'Hello world I am Bob')`. I did not time it, but I am sure regex is much slower. The only reason to use regex is if you want to do something more complex, e.g. replace the first two words whatever they are: `re.sub(r'^ *\w+ +\w+ +', '', 'Hello world I am Bob')`

Comment: Okay, I think I'll just go with your approach.  It makes sense, and it's simpler than trying to learn regular expression.